# Caching container images when using DinD in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-in-docker

We are using in-house-and-the-hard-way k8s cluster to run dynamic agents for CI workloads. Some of the workloads run inside Docker containers so that build process is the same on the developer's PC and CI system.

In the scenario where something needs to be done we pull several docker images and extract tools, files etc from them. There is a combined amount of 10GB of images that needs to be downloaded before the actual build takes place.

The idea is that we introduce image caching so that the pod start to build start time is significantly reduced.

##### Current solution (multiple DinDs):

As of today we are running 2 containers in a pod (one is a DinD sidecar and one is a CI agent). DinD container talks to the containerd running on a worker node (I think that's how it works) and CI agent talks to DinD using `DOCKER_HOST` set to `localhost`. Each new pod has a clean start since `/var/lib/docker/` is mounted as `emptyDir: {}`.

This solution works but since there is no caching, everything has to be re-pulled all the time.

##### Another solution we tried (single DinD):

We have tried running a single DinD container in a pod and then multiple CI agents pods which connect to it using it's `service`. DinD storage (`/var/lib/docker`) is mounted on a node's disk, using PV with `hostPath` and PVC. That means there is a single daemon for every worker pod. This is good, because all the images are cached and the pod start to build time is reduced to minimal.

This is bad because, there is single daemon and if multiple CI agents try to start a named container it will not allow it.

I think the main question is, how can this be achieved so that:

1. There is image caching in each CI agent pod, and
2. there exists a separation in terms of containers with the same name.

##### A doubtful solution

We were thinking to mount `/run/containerd/containerd.sock` on each worker node and leverage the existing image cache. Then using [kube-fledged](https://github.com/senthilrch/kube-fledged) to pre-pull a list of images we need. I'm not sure about this solution because it might be possible to interfere with containerd images that run the k8s platform, potentially breaking/destroying the cluster from CI agent pod e.g. running `docker prune` for example.

Comment: While of course having local cache is helpful in that it saves bandwidth and time pulling the image, the core issue, that I had, was the rate limit of Docker Hub. And to fix that, I used in my case the Nexus Repository 3 and had it cache the public images and image layers and make it available to DinD. Of course the GitLab-Runner still had to pull the images, but since they were cached and within the virtual network, it was much faster. I am not posting this as an answer, because it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Did you try a StatefulSet with a volumeClaimTemplate? This would give each dind it's own persistent volume.

Comment: same problem, we also solved it with StatefulSet and volumeClaimTemplate.